# Multiplying anonymous functions

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I've got variable which stores anonymous function e.g.

```
temp_f = @(x)((1/h^3)*(((xi+2*i)-x)^3-4*((xi+i)-x)^3))
```

I would like to multiply it by 'varA'  so in next step I could get

```
temp2_f = @(x) (temp_f(x) * varA)
```

how can I approach that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly as you've written it...

Comment: BTW, it is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `varA` to be an input argument to the new anonymous function, then:

```
temp2_f = @(x, varA) temp_f(x)*varA;
```

Comment: Yes, but then I'll get value of temp_f(x) and I want to have it in polynomial form.

Comment: @jsam_ what do you mean by "polynomial form"? are you trying to do symbolic computations? then you should look into `sym` and `MuPAD`